# Is it possible to apply an Xcode extension to multiple source files at once? If so, how?

Tags: xcode, xcode-extension

I want to write an Xcode extension that scans the source code for particular code fragments. However, it seems that such extension would work only on a per-file basis. For example, [here](https://github.com/BalestraPatrick/CleanClosureXcode) you can see that upon pushing a button only the current source file is changed. Is there a way to scan multiple source files at once?

Comment: alternate you could use Sourcery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible yet. As if you see the documentation in here

https://developer.apple.com/reference/xcodekit

the Framework has really a little few Classes, which none of them indicates multiple files... As you can see, you can edit text from Buffer from current opened tab in Xcode, which makes it a little bit complicated. The buffer can be used only in context of file (imagine hell of 10000000 lines of code loading into buffer and manipulating with such text) I believe in future apple will extend this to the max, but for now, we must be happy with what we have... Sorry for disappointing news.